# Set Default Paste Format In Microsoft Office Products

Tags: microsoft-office, copy-paste, text-formatting

I want to change the defaults for pasting in Microsoft Office.

Right now, it appears to default to keeping the source formatting, but I'd like to set the default to match the destination formatting.

I know how to right-click and select the desired type for each paste job, but I'd like to be able to use my hot keys (CTRL-V) or just right-click and Paste.

Answer (score 4):

## For Windows computers:

In Microsoft Office 2010 products and later you can set the default paste options in..

**File** > **Options** > **Advanced**

Scroll down to **Cut, copy, and paste** and set your desired defaults.

## For MacOS:

Office for Mac does not support this function currently. Possibly because MacOS handles copy/paste differently and has its own functions for setting paste defaults.

Open Mac **Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts**

Add a new App Shortcut to each of the Office products with the desired paste settings (such as "Paste and Match Formatting") mapped to <kbd>Command</kbd> - <kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see this option on macOS.

Comment: I've updated the answer @AdamJohns with recommend MacOS method.

Comment: How would you set up a 'Paste as Plain Text' shortcut?

Comment: That's not what this question is about and so we will not give you that answer here. If you cannot find another person asking that question, use the ASK QUESTION button and ask it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

music2myear's answer is still likely the best if you want to override the normal "Paste" command, but there is also an option to do:
<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> if you want to do the "Paste and Match Style" in Outlook or the equivalent "Paste and Match Formatting" in Word.

Achieving this in Excel and PowerPoint is still a different animal, since as near as I can tell there is not a direct menu option for this in those apps on a Mac.

Comment: This is good enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

For MacOS, you can use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and use custom keys `F13 to copy & F14 to paste` from [Complex Modification](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/complex_modifications/). Then press either of

- `Shift-F14` to Paste and Match Style
- `F15` to Paste and Match Style